# why is it necessary to differentiate between character and block devices?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, devices, block-device

I have been trying to read the source code for linux. I started watching a Youtube video which mentioned that character and block devices are different. It didn't say much about why it matters because once something is on the filesystem its the same.

Comment: Did you try Googling this?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I did take a look at that answer. I specifically wanted to know why is it so necessary to differentiate.

Comment: It's just historical. Block device drivers get access to common kernel routines for buffer caching and io scheduling.  As mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259193/what-is-a-block-device), FreeBSD has eliminated block devices and has a different framework for buffers and scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

This is just easy to understand
a block device can be read block to block
a character device is read char by char ...

/dev/random is char for example
/dev/tyy is char

etc...etc...

char devices can be controlled with special chars   like ctrl+G makes a physical serial console to emit a Beep for example....

the simpliest explaination : 
it depends on method needed to read/write to them