# what are possibilites for external devices to be named when mounted /dev/sd or /dev/mmc

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

A normal flash drive gets recognized as `/dev/sdX` by linux.

What is this raw `/dev/sdX` is called, specially before mounting.

When it gets mounted it will be like `/mountpath/sdX1` if it has one partition right?

What are the terminology here? how we name these?

What are other possibilities? I know `sdX` is supposed to mean SCSI, but what else can be expected when you attach a flash drive or external hard disk or maybe USB floppy drive/optical drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files in `/dev` are [special files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259193/what-is-a-block-device) that represent the block device. These files are created by kernel when the device is connected ([udev](https://opensource.com/article/18/11/udev) then creates multiple "user friendly" symlinks for them). You get separate device files for both the disk and partitions. The format/name depends on type of the device, most common are `/dev/sdX` for SATA/SCSI drives and `/dev/nvmenX` for NVMe drives (or to be more precise for NVMe namespaces), but other are also possible (`/dev/vdX` and `/dev/xvdX` for virtual drives, `/dev/hdX` for IDE drives, `/dev/mmcblkX` for eMMC cards etc.).

Partitions are always in format of *disk name + number* or *disk name + p + number* if the disk name ends with a number. So first partition will be `/dev/sda1` for the `sda` drive and `/dev/nvme0n1p1` for the `nvme0n1` NVMe drive (first namespace on it).

You then [mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)) these devices (or to be more precise filesystem on these devices) to a mount point to make content of the device (filesystem) available. Mount point is just a regular (empty) directory. You can name it whatever you want, the mount point name doesn't have to be related to the device at all -- when you mount the device, you specify the mount point like `mount /dev/sdxY /my/shiny/little/mountpoint`. Some user space tools that do the mounting from GUI use the filesystem label or UUID in the mount point, e.g. `/media/<username>/<filesystem label>`, but that's just a choice of the tool.

Answer (score 1):

if you look in linux under `/dev/disk` you will see the following folders

- `by-id/`
- `by-label/`
- `by-partlabel/`
- `by-partuuid/`
- `by-path/`
- `by-uuid/`

mounting a device *by name* I believe is the convention of just referring to `/dev/sdX#` and how linux maps more than one disk to sdb and sdc and so on is not reliable.

Instead mount by a more explicit convention, such as by label if you know you haven't labeled other disks with the same label, so for that reason you cannot rely on by-label 100% of the time.  I think the most common and most reliable is by-uuid.

the `lsblk` command is maybe the best tool to recognize disks connected to the system, but out of the box it comes up short.  Use the following alias and run `lsblk2` and you will get all the needed info to understand what's going on.

```
alias lsblk2='lsblk -o type,name,label,partlabel,size,fstype,model,serial,wwn,uuid'
```

then having the uuid to the disk you want to mount, you can then do so.

or see which `/dev/sd?#` it is linked to then do `mount /dev/sd?#  /whatever`